# How to run exit built in command in spring shell?

Tags: spring, shell, spring-shell

I'm using spring shell and it's work fine. but i want to run some built in command for example exit command in a method.
How can i do that?

```
@Component  
 public class runCommand implements CommandMarker {

    @CliCommand(value = "exit", help = "")
    public void exit() {
      // run exit built in command to exit
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/radhe-kishan/shell-example

Answer (score 0):

you can ref this, [disabling_specific_commands](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_disabling_specific_commands)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] disabledCommands = {"--spring.shell.command.exit.enabled=true"}; 
        String[] fullArgs = StringUtils.concatenateStringArrays(args, disabledCommands);
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, fullArgs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i run my app in command prompt with java -jar ... and not in main method. what should i do?

Comment: the code above means,you need add the code in your main or init function

Comment: This is how to disable some command. I want call a Built-in command with run another method defined in class?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to disable that command(In this case exit).
2. Next create a Subclass by extending the command class.
3. Next You can call command method from you subclass.

here is a example:

```
class CustomClear extends Clear {
    @ShellMethod(value="myClear")
    public void customCommand(){
        super.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Recommended way is to implement Clear.Command not directly extending the class, the second one didn't work for me.